# Addin to install other addins on installation won't open them

Tags: vba, excel, excel-addins

I wrote an addin, which adds other addins on installation, because deploying one Addin is easier than deploying a whole bunch of addins.

**Problem:** After the `End Sub` of the `Workbook_AddinInstall()` of the Bootloader-Addin, the just added/installed addin dissapear from the VBE, and aren't installed anymore. But they are still added to the addins-menu.

**Question:** I can install every addin by hand on every PC because it ain't a big number, but still this bugs me that I can't seem to find the faulty line. I'd appreciate every idea that comes to your mind to help me solve this problem.

**Bootloader Addin:**

```
Private Sub Workbook_AddinInstall()
    Const aiCount As Integer = 2
    Dim ai      As AddIn
    Dim aiTmp   As AddIn

    Dim i       As Integer
    Dim aiPath  As String

    Dim aiToBeInstalled(1 To aiCount) As String
    Dim aiInstalled(1 To aiCount)     As Boolean

    aiToBeInstalled(1) = "AddIn1.xla"
    aiToBeInstalled(2) = "AddIn2.xla"

    'AddIn added?
    For Each ai In AddIns
        For i = 1 To aiCount
            If ai.name = aiToBeInstalled(i) Then
                Set aiTmp = ai
                aiTmp.Installed = True
                aiInstalled(i) = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    Next ai

    'Add not already added AddIns
    For i = 1 To aiCount
        If Not aiInstalled(i) Then
            aiPath = GetDrivePath(volName:="somevolname", excludeDrives:="D") & _
                                "hidden\" & aiToBeInstalled(i)
            Set ai = AddIns.Add(aiPath, False)
            ai.Installed = True
        End If
    Next i

    Set ai = Nothing
    Set aiTmp = Nothing
End Sub ' After "End Sub" the addins are still added but not installed.
```

**Something interesting**
After installation of the bootloader if I run this Sub per `F5`, the Sub adds the addins just fine. And behaves like you'd expect it to.

**Edit:**
There are no crucial things called on `Workbook_AddinInstall` of the addins that are being installed, only some changes to the menu. Seeing that, this really confuses me. It behaves as if the addins aren't associated with the `Application` so they won't stay.

**Conclusion:** This is as far as I can go, if you have any ideas please let me know. I am currently working on a workaround but I'd really want to why this doesn't work.

Comment: Interesting. Is it possible that this procedure is triggering other events that uninstall the addins?

Comment: There is only one addin that runs Code within it's `Workbook_AddinInstall` - I will edit my answer later today to add the executed code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the add-in via the VB Editor for the current workbook project. The .Install() method will register the new GUID in the registry (as a COM object library) but doesn't persist the workbook reference..

```
'//Start Code Snippet 

'--!!-->   This will add the reference to the workbook (on each computer). 
    '-->    if the reference is not already registered it (will/should) take 
    '-->    care of it for you..

Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References.AddFromFile :YOUR_FILE_PATH_HERE


'//End Code Snippet
```

Obviously, replace **:YOUR_FILE_PATH_HERE** with the path of the addin location... Let me know if that helps. I have a few more tricks if it doesn't. Thanks, Brian.